# Why can't we find Ethernet checksum in Wireshark?

Tags: ethernet, protocol-theory

I am having a small question regarding Ethernet Frame Header Length.

As per my knowledge Ethernet Header size is 18 bytes without VLAN tag and 22 bytes if there is a VLAN tag.

But in Wireshark capture I am getting only 14 bytes without VLAN tag and 18 bytes with VLAN tag .

I found that there was a missing `checksum` field in my capture?

What happened in this case?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

On most hardware/platforms, the Ethernet checksum is handled by the NIC before it's passed up to Wireshark. There's no way (or really any reason) to pass this up to higher layers because of the fact that the NIC does this in hardware, unless you've coded the hardware/driver to behave this way. Refer to [the Ethernet wiki on wiki.wireshark.org](http://wiki.wireshark.org/Ethernet) for more information.